# Change route uri segment dynamically in links in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, dynamic-url

I have links in my blade view that corresponds to a route like this:

```
http://www.myforum.com/channel/2
```

where **2** is the id of the channel. Now what i want is that when user hovers over that link they see my channel name or a slug instead of the id, whereas i still want to link to that route with id. That is, i want to write,

```
<a href="{{ route('channel.show',['channel'=>$channel->id]) }}"> {{ $channel->title }}</a>
```

but users will see and indeed will be taken to the page which has the url:

```
http://www.myforum.com/channel/laravel-discussions
```

is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use title

```
<a href="{{ route('channel.show',['channel'=>$channel->id]) }}" title=" {{ $channel->title }}"> {{ $channel->title }}</a>
```

As per your question you cant hide bottom url .still you to hide then yuo can use # and on ajax you can submit it

if slug is unique then you can use slug instead of id

One more option is onclick

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href='{{ route('channel.show',['channel'=>$channel->id]) }}'"  title=" {{ $channel->title }}"> {{ $channel->title }}</a>
```